# How to load in txt file as data in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm learning how to use sklearn and scikit and all that to do some machine learning.

I was wondering how to import this as data?

[image]

This is a dataset from the million song genre dataset.

How can I make my `data.target[0]` equal to "classic pop and rock" (as 0) and `data.target[1]` equal to 0 which is "classic pop and rock" and `data.target[640]` equal to 1 which is "folk"?

And my `data.data[0,:]` be equal to `-8.697`, `155.007`, 1, 9, and so forth (all numerical values after the title column)

Comment: It looks like you've got csv formatted data, try using the csv module to read it in: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Give a sample of what you want the data structure to look like, your description is confusing. Also, post any code that you have tried so far, SO isn't a code writing service. Lastly, the basic approach would be to read lines in a loop until the first character is '%' and then start building your data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as others had mentioned it was a little unclear as to what shape you were looking for, but just as a general starter, and getting the data into a very flexible format, you could read the text file into python and convert it to a pandas dataframe. I am certain their are other more compact ways of doing this, but just to provide clear steps we could start with:

```
import pandas as pd
import re 

file = 'filepath' #this is the file path to the saved text file
music = open(file, 'r')
lines = music.readlines()
# split the lines by comma
lines = [line.split(',') for line in lines]
# capturing the column line
columns = lines[9]
# capturing the actual content of the data, and dismissing the header info
content = lines[10:]

musicdf = pd.DataFrame(content)
# assign the column names to our dataframe
musicdf.columns = columns
# preview the dataframe
musicdf.head(10)

# the final column had formatting issues, so wanted to provide code to get rid of the "\n" in both the column title and the column values

def cleaner(txt):
    txt = re.sub(r'[\n]+', '', txt)
    return txt

# rename the column of issue
musicdf = musicdf.rename(columns = {'var_timbre12\n' : 'var_timbre12'})

# applying the column cleaning function above to the column of interest
musicdf['var_timbre12'] = musicdf['var_timbre12'].apply(lambda p: cleaner(p))

# checking the top and bottom of dataframe for column var_timbre12
musicdf['var_timbre12'].head(10)
musicdf['var_timbre12'].tail(10)
```

the result of this would be the following:

```
             %genre            track_id       artist_name  
0  classic pop and rock  TRFCOOU128F427AEC0  Blue Oyster Cult   
1  classic pop and rock  TRNJTPB128F427AE9F  Blue Oyster Cult
```

By having the data in this format, you can now do lots of grouping tasks, finding certain genres and their relative attributes, etc. using pandas groupby function.

Hope this helps!